# All local changes removed on update

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am working under a Java project together with one of my collegues. Project sources are hosted in private GitHub repository. We are both using IntelliJ Idea 13 to work with it - commit changes and update project from Git repository. The whole IntelliJ Idea project is also in GIT repository.

The issue is that sometimes (approximately after a few commits/updates, can't say for sure since that happens randomly) Idea decides to remove ALL of my local changes and just take whatever comes with an update from Git. Under ALL I mean ALL - all new files, all changes, all resources - whatever was changed locally and not yet committed. Usually update goes well and even if something should be merged - Idea offers a merge dialog where issues can be resolved, so this is not about merging changes for sure.

It is also not an OS-related issue since we've been working on different platforms (at least Win XP/7/8, Ubuntu and Mac OS X) - that issue happens everywhere.

I have been looking for the solution of this issue for some time now and didn't find even a single thread about it, so I have decided to ask here - probably someone might give me some tips. Probably I don't know something about GIT since I didn't actually work with it a lot.

Since this case it pretty vague I am not sure which information I should add to the topic to clarify the situation.

Thanks a lot in advance!

*P.S.

A wild guess - IntelliJ Idea has a `workspace.xml` file in its project files which represents user-related settings of work area plus some other stuff - it is also in GIT in our project and ocasionally gets committed with other changes, might that cause this issue?*

Comment: You should never store anything related to your development environment within source control.  Instead, only store the source and any resources needed by the program.

Comment: I suggest you not to commit workspace.xml in each change cause all changes to this file are not helpful. make a default workspace.xml , commit that and put workspace.xml in your gitignore.

Comment: Totally agree with MadProgrammer here.

Comment: Just to make sure - Each of you & your co have a cloned repository?

Comment: @laune yes, we have cloned repositories

Comment: @MadProgrammer this might be a good tip for a large project (not always though) but for our case configuring the project on each separate machine and keeping these settings up to date is a pain and will only cause more issues and time-waste, storing base project settings (all instead workspace.xml) in GIT removes all that pain

Comment: One more thing - we just got this issue after an update where only java files came with an update, so I doubt this is somehow related to the project - more like IntelliJ Idea issue or something I am unaware of and accidentally using/touching

Comment: And introduces others ;)

Comment: Except this one (which seems to appear only on this project) I didn't see anything else, so what is the problem? Also if the project is complicated and contains hundreds of librabries, dependencies and artifacts - creating the project from a scratch or copying it is not an option. I know that every developer wants everything to be perfect and such, but its really not the best case to apply perfectionism to. No offence :)